# Creating arrays from user input in Java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I need to create two arrays: 1 for playerJersey and 2 for playerRating. I need to output the player jersey number with the corresponding rating. Why are my arrays not being assigned the correct values?
This is what I currently have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class PlayerRoster {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
          Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
          final int MAX_PLAYERS = 5;
          int [] playerJersey = new int [MAX_PLAYERS];
          int [] playerRating = new int [MAX_PLAYERS];
          int i;
          
          for (i = 0; i < playerJersey[i]; ++i){
          playerJersey[i] = scnr.nextInt();
          }
          for (i = 0; i < playerRating[i]; ++i){
          playerRating[i] = scnr.nextInt();
          }
          for (i = 0; i < MAX_PLAYERS; ++i){
             System.out.println("Enter player " + playerJersey[i] + "'s jersey number:");
             System.out.println(playerJersey[i]);
             System.out.println("Enter player " + playerRating[i] + "'s rating:");
             System.out.println(playerRating[i]);
             
          }
          
          
       }
    }
```

This is the current output:

Enter player 0's jersey number:
0

Enter player 0's rating:
0

Enter player 0's jersey number:
0

Enter player 0's rating:
0

Enter player 0's jersey number:
0

Enter player 0's rating:
0

Enter player 0's jersey number:
0

Enter player 0's rating:
0

Enter player 0's jersey number:
0

Enter player 0's rating:
0

Answer (score 0):

Note, you're going through `playerJersey[i]` in your first two for loops, which you're probably not wanting to do.
Your first two `for` loops should be similar to your last `for` loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAX_PLAYERS; ++i){
...
}
```